# git: master branch history was changed out from under me

Tags: git, git-rebase

Imagine two branches: `master` & `my_branch`. `my_branch` was branched off `master`.

I've been working along quite happily on a project and it was tabled for about a month. Foolishly I forgot to still rebase `my_branch` to `master` daily.

However, even that shouldn't be a problem, I would think. Unless someone rewrote history directly in `master`. I'm pretty sure someone did this: went back and changed commits by squashing, removing commits, or other ways that change history.

When I try to rebase to master, I get tons of conflicts with files only in my branch. This completely mystifies me. Not only that, I see the same conflicts with each step of the rebase (once they first appear). I resolve them all and continue the rebase and in the next step I have the same conflicts.

How might this have happened and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Force-pushing after rewriting history of a branch is a possibility in git.... it's not recommended to be done in branches where other people might be working after you push it.... when that happens, there is _pain_ to go through.... as you my attest to right now. It's not something to be too worried about anyway.... if `my_branch` is a straight line after you started it from `master`, then you should be able to get yourself on top of the _new_ master by doing: `git rebase --onto origin/master the-old-master-as-I-have-it my_branch`.

Comment: You can get rebase with "repeating the same file many times" without remote history modifications, if you worked on the same file with newer commits in master. I'd suggest to merge upstream instead to resolve conflicts only once - it's not the best usually, but sometimes it can save a lot of pain and possible mistakes.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by this, " I get TONS of conflicts with files only in my branch" ? Do you mean they are new files that you created on your branch and they don't exist in `master`?

Comment: Also, it's not clear whether you confirmed if someone forced pushed `master`, or if you are just guessing that's what happened. It should be easy to confirm if your local `master` is diverged from `origin/master`? Or, try `git merge-base origin/master my_branch` and see if the commit ID returned is the same commit ID on your branch where you last started from. You could also stare at `git log origin/master my_branch --graph` to see if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

> Foolishly I forgot to still rebase `my_branch` to `master` daily. My fail.

Actually, if `master`'s history was rewritten, your daily rebase would not have changed anything: the next rebase on top of the "new" `master` would still be a mess to resolve.

If a `git fetch` + `git log --all --branches --oneline --graph --decorate` visually confirms that your local `master` and `origin/master` have completely diverged, then yes, cherry-picking your commits on top of the new `master` would be the quickest way to include your work back to `master`.

```
git rebase --onto origin/master $(git merge-base master my_branch) my_branch
```

This assumes you did not do a `git pull` on `master`.